# Adjoints of the forgetful functor from Simp to Hypergraph

Tags: general-topology, adjoint-functors

I need to find the left and right adjoint of forgetful functor from the category ${\bf Simp}$ to the category of ${\bf Hypergraph}$.

Hypergraphs are generalizations of a graph such that an edge can join any number of vertices.  A hypergraph is a pair $ H =(X,E)$ such that $X$ is the set of elements called nodes or vertices and $E$ is the non-empty subsets of $X$ or edges.

Also, need to find the unit and counit of these adjunctions.

Comment: What is $\mathbf{Simp}$?  And what are the morphisms in each category?

Comment: ${\bf Simp} $ is the simplicial category where the objects are simplicial complexes and the morphisms are the set of all simplicial maps.  The category of hypergraphs is described here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/hypergraph